# Doctrine 2 setting a boolean back to null

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Doctrine2 entity with a type boolean using a tinyint in mysql to store the result.  On the initial add of a value I can set it to null.  If I save as 0 or 1 any new value I pass in other than a 0 or 1 saves as a 0.

Below is the variable with get and set methods.  I have done a var_dump to confirm that the value is being set to null before it saves as 0.

```
 /**
 * @var string $completed
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_completed", type="boolean", length=1, nullable=true)
 * @Api(type="field")
 */
private $completed;

 /**
 * Set completed
 *
 * @param boolean $value
 */
public function setCompleted($value = null)
{
    if ($value=='') {
        $value = null;
    }
    $this->completed = $value;
}

/**
 * Get completed
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getCompleted()
{
    if (is_null($this->completed)) {
        $this->completed = '';
    }
    return $this->completed;
}
```

Comment: It's probably not the cause, but getters shouldn't have side effects (your getter actually modifies the value in some circumstances).

Comment: did you ever have any luck with this?

Comment: I never got it to save as a null, though I had implemented a work around pretty quickly after this post.  Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```php
public function setCompleted($value = null)
{
    if ('' === $value) {
        $value = null;
    }
    $this->completed = $value ? true : false;
}
```

Assuming that, when passing an empty string you want `null`, otherwise you want `true` or `false` based on default PHP behaviour of `$value`.

And as suggested, no side effects in getters! This should be exactly the same as your `getCompleted`, as long as you use the above setter:

```php
public function getCompleted()
{
    if (null === $this->completed)) {
        return '';
    }

    return $this->completed;
}
```

Comment: Whatever is going wrong the issue isn't with the setting of the value within the entity.  $this->completed is being set to null as desired both your way and mine, but when the save occurs a 1 saves as a 1 and anything else, including null, saves as a 0.

Comment: This is going to set anything that is "falsy" to false (0)